# Golang and deploy serve

Tags: http, go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

type MyHandler struct{}

func (h *MyHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello Internet,Goodbye Local")
}
func main() {
    handler := MyHandler{}
    server := http.Server{
        Addr:    "127.0.0.1:8080",
        Handler: &handler,
    }
    server.ListenAndServe()
}
```

For what I have written (func(h *MyHandler)...)? I don't understand How does this snippet impact on code if I don't call him from func main ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The http server starts with a reference to `handler`, which is of type `MyHandler`. `MyHandler` is a type with a method `ServeHTTP(ResponseWriter,*Request)`, so it implements the `http.Handler` interface. Thus, whenever the server calls `Handler.ServeHTTP`, the `MyHandler.ServeHTTP` method is called.